# What does this error mean?: begin document ended by end proof

Tags: environments

I'm typing up an article in Latex and after opening the proof environment with `\begin{proof}` and concluding it with `\end{proof}` I get the error message

> ! LaTeX Error: `\begin{document}` ended
>   by `\end{proof}`.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.

Does anybody know how to fix this? If I delete both the `\begin{proof}` and `\end{proof}` commands then it goes through as usual but I don't get the nice proof environment in the document.

Comment: nevermind, I'd forgotten amsthm

Comment: @long: could you post your minimal code here?

Comment: Well done for solving your problem!  We'll probably close this question just for housekeeping.

Comment: @Andrew: Why don't we ask him/her to delete this question?

Comment: Actually, @long trail, could you please post an answer and accept it. This seems like something that could happen to other people too.

Comment: On reflection, I agree with Caramdir: it would have been useful to have this recorded with its answer.  (But I'm not sure it's worth going through the reopen cycle to get it.)